Use of big-oh notation in Apostol's number theory book
In Apostol's book on analytic number theory, I came across the following computation:
$\sum_{d \leq x}\sum_{q \leq \frac{x}{d}}1 = \sum_{d \leq x} \dfrac{x}{d} + O(1) = x\sum_{d \leq x} \dfrac{1}{d} + O(x) $
I assumed there was an implicit use of a result of the form $f_i \in O(g_i) \implies \sum_{n \leq x} f_n(x) \in O \left(\sum_{n \leq x}g_n(x)\right)$. However, the example $\sum_{n \leq x} n \notin O(x)$ quickly shows this to be false. I am unable to justify the steps used, and was hoping somebody could help clarify the same.
Thank you.

What is needed is for the term $O(f(n))$ to have its implicit constant bounded by a value independent of $n$. Then you can work with the $\sum$.

I assume good understanding of the definition of the O notation given by Apostol.
The sum $\sum_{q\leq x/d}1$ is the number of positive integers bounded by $x/d$, it is the integer part of $x/d$ with you can write as $x/d-\{x/d\}$ where $\{x/d\}$ is non negative and less than $1$. So:
$$
\sum_{d\leq x}
\sum_{q\leq x/d}1=\sum_{d\leq x}\left(\frac{x}{d}-\left\{\frac{x}{d}\right\}\right)=x\sum_d\frac{x}{d}-\sum_{d\leq x}\left\{\frac{x}{d}\right\}
$$
Now
$$
\biggl\lvert\sum_{d\leq x}\left\{\frac{x}{d}\right\}\biggr\rvert\leq\sum_{d\leq x}1\leq x 
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{d\leq x}\left\{\frac{x}{d}\right\}=O(x). 
$$

So the actual error term matters here I see. There's multiple instances in the book where the sum is passed into $O$. Looks like I need to actually check the error terms there as well. Thank you for the answer!
